# Is there any way to change button color after doing process like if condition in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a tool that help me to my work, so I want to change the button color to green if ping is successful and unsuccessful if not.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("ping Tool")

def ping(*branch):
    for ip in branch:
        response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
        if "Received = 4" in response:
            print(f"up {ip} Ping Successful")
        else:
            print(f"Down {ip} Ping Unsuccessful")

def ping201():
    ping('4.2.2.2')

def ping202():
    ping('8.8.8.8')

button = ttk.Button(window, text='branch1', command=ping201)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = ttk.Button(window,text='branch2',command=ping202)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

button = ttk.Button(window,text='Exit',command=window.quit)
button.grid(pady=20)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of printing the status, change the color of the button widget.

Comment: You can't change the background color on OSX, but you can on other operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using closures. Closures are functions defined within other functions. The outer function *inherits* the variable scope to the inner function. Thus, allowing us to store a specific state only available and specific to every new instance of the inner function.

For each assignment of `command=ping(...)` a newly defined inner function (closure) is returned. The value of `button` and `*branch` is specific to every new instance of `onCommand`.

For details, see Python's LEGB rule (local, enclosing, global and built-in): https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

The background color itself can be changed using `button.config(background='green')`.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("ping Tool")

def ping(button, *branch):
    def onCommand():
        for ip in branch:
            response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
            if "Received = 4" in response:
                print(f"up {ip} Ping Successful")
                button.config(background='green')
            else:
                print(f"Down {ip} Ping Unsuccessful")
                button.config(background='red')
    return onCommand

button = Button(window, text='branch1')
button.config(command=ping(button, '4.2.2.2'))
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = Button(window,text='branch2')
button.config(command=ping(button, '8.8.8.8'))
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

button = Button(window,text='Exit',command=window.quit)
button.grid(pady=20)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Gerald Mayr, that's exactly what i want ..... many thankssss